# getimagesize() not working in PHP 7.1

Tags: php, php-7.1, getimagesize

I have a code that gets an imgur link and fetches the height and width of the image using the simple:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($link);
```

I was running PHP 7.1 and everything worked fine until I got to the use of getimagesize(). When the function was called it returned false everytime. I then reverted back to PHP 5.3 and the code worked immediately.

I just wanted to ask whether there was a reason getimagesize() stopped working in 7.1? The documentation says PHP 7 so I guess I am just confused.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `list()` that isn't failing? http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php says: *"**Warning** In PHP 5, list() assigns the values starting with the right-most parameter. In PHP 7, list() starts with the left-most parameter."* so this could also apply to 7.1. See the Changelog also.

Comment: That's weird ... it should work! lol I am gona test that right away

Comment: Ah yes list() would make more sense lol Nice find Fred!

Comment: It's possible, however I did try to variable dump just the getimagesize($link) and it returned NULL. Is this the normal response?

Comment: so check for `$link` then. That could be failing (also). @Mac could be a path issue and/or permissions. Use error reporting also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php but do check the `list()` manual and try again.

Comment: you'll (probably) need to post more code for this, along with the variables' values. If not, then there's an answer below you can look at. This could even be something totally different also. Question's unclear.

Comment: I've now moved on, since there is no more activity in the question regarding comments/answer/asking for an update to the question. I voted to close the question as unclear, since it is for a few reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best guess, $link is an url, which means that it requires the php.ini setting `allow_url_fopen` to be `true` for getimagesize to check it, and you have it to `true` in php5's php.ini, and `false` in php7's php.ini - that would cause the problem you're describing. an alternative, compatible with both php versions and both php.ini settings, would be:

```
$tmp=tmpfile();
$file=stream_get_meta_data($tmp)['uri'];
$ch=curl_init($link);
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_FILE=>$tmp,
CURLOPT_ENCODING=>''
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
fclose($tmp); // << explicitly deletes the file, freeing up disk space etc~ - though php would do this automatically at the end of script execution anyway.
```

edit: as pointed out by @marekful , the original proposed workaround code would give the wrong result. the updated code should give the correct result.

edit: fixed some code-breaking typos (in the variable names)

Comment: Didn't the OP want dimensions and you are giving an answer for size in bytes? (PHP function name is a bit misleading...)

Comment: @marekful holy ** yeah, you're right, thanks. removed the proposed workaround for now.

Comment: OP's either AWOL or nothing that was said in comments and/or the answer solved this. Ya gotta love "the silent type" eh?

Comment: @Fred-ii- give him some time lol. for all we know, he could have been caught up in an emergency, and come back tomorrow

Comment: @hanshenrik I have and I believe there had more than enough time to re-test/debug and keep us informed as to what's going on (or not). I fail to see interaction on their part since, not to mention your answer being accepted or them commenting about it in any way. Time can only tell I guess.

Comment: @hanshenrik Thank you for your answer! The issue was in the php.ini & turning on fopen.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you also for your help.